# ANALYZE fails on postgres 12 with COLLATE issue

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit

I have a table with definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.e13010
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_e13010'::regclass),
    directive integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
    guid uuid NOT NULL,
    objectid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid,
    patchid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    usercode character varying(1024) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    documentbegindate timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    documentenddate timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    actualbegindate timestamp(0) without time zone,
    actualenddate timestamp(0) without time zone,
    state integer,
    state_tmp integer,
    statedate timestamp(0) without time zone,
    lastchangedate timestamp(0) without time zone,
    automaticallyadded smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    removeleft smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    removeright smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    objectdel integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    recordtype integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    c1783376938461729511 character varying(370) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c8592504141572910447 character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c3151508878674189688 character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c5466475963604233069 uuid,
    c2451458188274224198 character varying(14) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c1334152289464091201 character varying(12) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c8454855336468783092 character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c6935852433552846825 character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c4829935149242607681 character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c7130228457076369754 timestamp(0) without time zone,
    c7401857868825271194 character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c4321258757347250429 character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c7827471130056322929 character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c2981260259601811850 uuid,
    c3564911216734280263 uuid,
    c6652429068516103637 uuid,
    c6755579201904122041 uuid,
    c4812253808410943281 integer,
    c8041209163526932724 uuid,
    c2437585203524691466 character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c4137474161116073468 character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c8768589751025308865 character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    c6556487635275527483 character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT pk13010 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.e13010
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: idx_e13010_code

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_code;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_code
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (c1783376938461729511 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_doc

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_doc;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_doc
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (c8592504141572910447 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, c8454855336468783092 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, state ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(usercode, documentbegindate, documentenddate, c8041209163526932724)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_esiaid

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_esiaid;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_esiaid
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (c4321258757347250429 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, state ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(usercode, documentbegindate, documentenddate)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_guid

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_guid;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_e13010_guid
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (guid ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_inn

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_inn;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_inn
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (c1334152289464091201 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(usercode, documentbegindate, documentenddate, state)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_key_state

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_key_state;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_key_state
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (usercode COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, state ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(objectid, guid, patchid, documentbegindate, documentenddate, state_tmp)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_objectid

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_objectid;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_objectid
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (objectid ASC NULLS LAST, state ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(id, guid, patchid, documentbegindate, documentenddate, removeleft, removeright, objectdel, state_tmp, usercode)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_pid_key_id

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_pid_key_id;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_pid_key_id
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (patchid ASC NULLS LAST, usercode COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, id ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(guid, objectid, documentbegindate, documentenddate, state, state_tmp, automaticallyadded, directive, recordtype, objectdel)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_pid_oid_id

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_pid_oid_id;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_pid_oid_id
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (patchid ASC NULLS LAST, objectid ASC NULLS LAST, id ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(documentbegindate, documentenddate, removeleft, removeright, objectdel)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_select_patch_pos

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_select_patch_pos;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_select_patch_pos
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (patchid ASC NULLS LAST, id ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(documentbegindate, documentenddate, automaticallyadded, objectid)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: idx_e13010_snils

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_e13010_snils;

CREATE INDEX idx_e13010_snils
    ON public.e13010 USING btree
    (c2451458188274224198 COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, state ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(usercode, documentbegindate, documentenddate)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

It has 300k rows within and of course have a TOAST-table. When I try to execute

`ANALYZE e13010`

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  could not determine which collation to use for string comparison
HINT:  Use the COLLATE clause to set the collation explicitly.
SQL state: 42P22
```

Please tell what the cause may affect ANALYZE this way? I think it somehow relates to TOAST-functionality but have no clue how.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it too on my server. But our customer infrastructure leads to this bug. And I can't find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: If you want help, you have to show how to reproduce the behavior.